# Arel in SQLite and other databases

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new in databases and Ruby on rails applications.

I have a question about generating queries from ORM.

When my database is SQLite, and I am using a code for creating queries for this database, if I change my database am I still able to use the same code?

In addition, when I am using Arel, because it provides more ready methods for more complex queries, before I am generating a query I call the method .to_sql
If I want to use the same code but for another database am I still able to execute the query? Using instead of to_sql something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Ruby on Rails code is portable between databases without doing anything more than adjusting your config/database.yml file (for connection details) and updating your Gemfile (to use the correct database adapter gem).

Database portability is mostly likely when you do not rely on specific, hardcoded uses of SQL as a way to invoke queries. Instead use the Rails' associations, relations, and query tools wherever possible. Specific SQL often creeps in on .where() clauses, so be thoughtful there and minimize/simply those as much as practical (for instance, multiple simple scopes that can be chained may give you better results than trying larger more complex single scopes).  Also use Arel.matches when depending on "LIKE" type clauses instead of hardcoding LIKE details in .where() calls because different databases (such as PostgreSQL) handle case-sensitivity differently.

Your best defense against surprises upon switching databases is a robust set of automated unit (e.g., Rspec, minitest) and integration tests (e.g., capybera). These are especially important where you are unable to avoid use of specific SQL coding (say for optimization or odd/complex queries).

Since SQLite is simpler than most other robust engines like MySQL or Postgres, you're likely to be safer anyway in any operations you depend on.   You're most vulnerable when using some advanced or specific feature of the database, but you're also generally more aware if you're doing that, so can write protective tests to help warn you upon switching database engines.

Comment: Another relative question is: if you are working with relational database, then the changes in your code would not be so much, but changing into a key, value database, like Mongo DB, then there are a lot of changes?

Comment: Yes, Rails's ActiveRecord is based around SQL relational databases.  You would likely need to use ActiveModel with Mongoid or MongoMapper to properly work with MongoDB.   When you think about it though, this means that your model architecture as an object model is different in general, not merely because of the database mechanics, so it's appropriate to revisit your design anyway (ORM = object-relational mapping implying a relational database).

Comment: Yes this is also what I think. Thank you very much for your input! :)

Comment: You bet, glad to be of help.  Good luck!